# Removing files with a certain extension except one file from terminal

Tags: bash, command-line

I need to remove all files with .gif extension except one file with name say "filename.gif". What is the optimal way to go about doing this in terminal?

The command rm `*.gif` removes all gif files including the file `filename.gif`.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Here's the simple solution you should probably use:

```
mv filename.gif filename.gif.keep
rm *.gif
mv filename.gif.keep filename.gif
```

There's nothing special about the `.keep` extension, this just makes it so that the filename temporarily doesn't end in `.gif`.

If you must not rename the file (and there are *scripting* situations where this is important):

```
for X in *.gif; do
    if [ "$X" != "filename.gif" ]; then
        rm "$X"
    fi
done
```

Or you can write it shorter like this:

```
for X in *.gif; do [ "$X" != "filename.gif" ] && rm "$X"; done
```

You may prefer to use `find` instead; it's very powerful, you *might* consider it more readable, and it better handles *weird filenames with characters like `*` in them*.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name 'filename.gif' -name '*.gif' -delete
```

I've used the `-not` operator for readability, but if [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliance is important--if you're not using GNU find, or if this is for a script you intend to redistribute to others or run on a variety of systems--you should use the `!` operator instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'filename.gif' -name '*.gif' -delete
```

One handy thing about `find` is that you can easily modify the command for case-insensitivity, so that it finds and deletes files with extensions like `.GIF` too:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name 'filename.gif' -iname '*.gif' -delete
```

Please note that I've used `-iname` in place of `-name` for the search pattern `*.gif` but I have *not* used it for `filename.gif`. Presumably you know exactly what your file is called, and `-iname` will match alternate capitalization not just in the *extension*, but anywhere in the filename.

All these solutions **only delete files residing immediately in the current directory**. They don't delete files not contained in the current directory, and they don't delete files that reside in subdirectories of the current directory.

If you want to delete files everywhere contained within the current directory (that is, including in subdirectories, and in subdirectories of those subdirectories, and so forth--files contained within the current directory or any of its descendants), use `find` *without* `maxdepth -1`:

```
find . -not -name 'filename.gif' -name '*.gif' -delete
```

Be careful with this!

You can also set other values with `-maxdepth`. For example, to delete files in the current directory and its children and grandchildren but not any deeper:

```
find . -maxdepth 3 -not -name 'filename.gif' -name '*.gif' -delete
```

Just make sure you never put `-delete` first, before the other expressions! You'll see I've always put `-delete` at the end. If you put it at the beginning, it would be evaluated first, and *all* the files under `.` (including files not ending in `.gif` and files in deep sub-sub-sub...directories of `.`) would be deleted!

**For more information**, see the manual pages for [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/bash.1.html) and [`sh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/sh.1.html) and for the commands used in these examples: [`mv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mv.1.html), [`rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/rm.1.html), [`[`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/test.1.html), and (especially) [`find`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/find.1.html).

Comment: Thanks Eliah. I did it similar to the first method you have suggested i.e. to convert the file in a different format and convert it back. But that seemed a bit sub-optimal and unclean. I like the second approach you and @efthialex have suggested and I am using it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Marvis I'm glad this met your needs. By the way, I've expanded this answer with information about another method (or class of methods) using `find`, which is highly versatile.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer `find` is indeed a good find.

Comment: +1 for the commonsense (move-delete-move) answer.

Comment: Nit-pick: how does `find` handle weird filenames with `*` in them better than the for-loop? The for loop handles files with `*` fine, because you've used double quotes.

Comment: @Flimm *This particular application* of a for loop handles them fine (though it doesn't handle some other weird filenames fine, such as filenames that contain `$` followed by another character). *In general*, `find` handles weird filenames (including those with `*`) better than a for loop because--at least with `-delete`--you don't have to worry about quoting or escaping anything.

Comment: @EliahKagan: it handles filenames that begin with a `$` just fine. When you surround a variable name with double quotes in bash, like this: `"$variablename"`, the variable contents are passed as-is to the command, no interpolation happens at all. The only issue then are files beginning with a dash, because `rm` might interpret it as an option. To fix that, you would need to run `rm -- "$X"` instead of `rm "$X"`. You're right that with `find -delete` you don't have to think about it.

Answer (score 27):

If you're using `bash` (the default shell), the `extglob` shell option allows you to use an extended pattern matching syntax.  To enable it, use the `shopt` builtin command:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

(I include that line in my `.bashrc` file.)

Among other things, it grants access to the `!()` operator, which matches any pattern not inside the parens.  For your purpose:

```
rm !(filename).gif
```

More information is available in `man bash` under "Pattern Matching".

Comment: Excellent answer! It's bash-specific so may not be suitable for portable scripting, but interactive tasks and even some scripting, this is hands-down the best way to go. It carries the added complexity that `extglob` must be enabled, but nothing bad happens if it's *disabled* (in that case, this just doesn't work). And it seems to be enabled by default, even though I don't have `shopt -s extglob` in any of my (or the global) configuration files. If there's a simple explanation for why it works for me out of the box, you may want to add it to this answer; or I may post a new question.

Answer (score 13):

Open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
find . -type f -name "*.gif" -and -not -name "filename.gif" -exec rm -vf {} \;
```

The difference between `-delete` and `-exec rm -vf {} \;` is that with the second option, you will be able to see which files have been removed, because of the `-v` flag. That's something that can't be done with the `-delete` option. (`-name -delete` will print the filenames, but `rm` with `-v` reveals if each file was *successfully* deleted.)

Answer (score 1):

There's the `GLOBIGNORE` variable. From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html):

```
GLOBIGNORE
      A colon-separated list of patterns defining the set of filenames
      to be ignored by pathname expansion.  If a filename matched by a
      pathname expansion pattern also matches one of the  patterns  in
      GLOBIGNORE, it is removed from the list of matches.
```

So, a simple way is to just set `GLOBGINORE` to the filename in question:

```
$ touch {a,b,c,d}.png
$ echo *.png
a.png b.png c.png d.png
$ GLOBIGNORE=c.png
$ echo *.png
a.png b.png d.png
```

So, in your case:

```
GLOBIGNORE=filename.gif; rm *.gif
```

Of course, since `GLOBIGNORE` contains patterns, you can use it whenever you want to exclude a pattern:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='[a-c].png'; echo *.png
d.png
$ touch bd.png; GLOBIGNORE='?.png'; echo *.png
bd.png
```

---

An advantage (?!) of `GLOBIGNORE` is that setting [it automatically excludes `.` and `..`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105467/70524) from being matched, and it enables `dotglob`:

```
The  GLOBIGNORE shell variable may be used to restrict the set of file‐
names matching a pattern.  If GLOBIGNORE is set, each matching filename
that also matches one of the patterns in GLOBIGNORE is removed from the
list of matches.  The filenames ``.''  and ``..''  are  always  ignored
when  GLOBIGNORE is set and not null.  However, setting GLOBIGNORE to a
non-null value has the effect of enabling the dotglob shell option,  so
all other filenames beginning with a ``.''  will match.  To get the old
behavior of ignoring filenames beginning with a ``.'', make ``.*''  one
of  the  patterns  in  GLOBIGNORE.  The dotglob option is disabled when
GLOBIGNORE is unset.
```

So, a simple way of deleting *all* files and folders in a directory:

```
GLOBIGNORE=.; rm -r *
```

The `*` will match filenames beginning with `.`, since `GLOBIGNORE` enabled `dotglob`, but it won't match `.` or `..`, so you won't affect the parent directory that way.