# How to delete all files except one named file from a specific folder

Tags: command-line

Here is the situation.

I have a directory which contains many files with different extensions. I want to delete all files except one with a specific name.

This could be easily done using the GUI by selecting all and pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and deselecting the file in question.

That is exactly what I want to, but how can I do it from the command line?

**For example:**  dirA contains the following files:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.php
d.html
a.db
b.db
e.html
```

I want to delete all files keeping only the file named `a.txt`.

Comment: I think [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/256521/removing-files-with-a-certain-extension-except-one-file-from-terminal) might explain. ;)

Comment: I've come to this before, but this needs more work

Comment: These questions are confusing me, not to mention they have no idea how many files are on your system with . Or .txt, use this command simple to use and easy to understand rm -riv ~/Desktop/path/*     * = all in folder , r = recursive , v = verbose , i = prompt you before deleting

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I've come with this easy simple great command:

```
rm !(a.txt)
```

you can use ! as a negation

Test the glob with echo first i.e.

```
echo !(a.txt)
```

If it doesn't work,  for `bash` you may need to enable this with

```
shopt -s extglob
```

If you wanted to keep both `a.txt` and `b.txt`, you can use `!(a.txt|b.txt)` or `!([ab].txt)`.

**Edit:**

to make `rm` working recursively just add `-r` like

```
rm -r !(a.txt)
```

and also, it is working with folder. just need to change the name to the dir name, such as for `a_dir`

```
rm -r !(a_dir)
```

Comment: I never see such thing before now, I discover it by change lol. Commands are magical

Comment: What shell does this work on? Does it work on ubuntu's default bash? EDIT: nevermind, found the info, proposed an edit.

Comment: From one test I ran, it looks like `echo !()` makes the shell non-responsive.  [Which is not a problem with the present use of the `!(filename)` form, just a curiosity.]

Comment: Seems to be dependent on ksh. Bash doesn't like it.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, you can add -r to rm command like this `rm -r !(a.txt)`, it will work recursively

Comment: Worked for me like a charm on 16LTS through bash

Comment: As a new user to Ubuntu I am curious to know what this command has done? shopt -s extglob ,
I am curious as it helped me.

Comment: For me running this on mac it returns `-bash: !: event not found`

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: My zsh reports `number expected` :(.

Answer (score 23):

You can try this command:

```
find . \! -name 'a.txt' -delete
```

But you need be careful because find command is recursive.

Comment: You can prevent `find` from being recursive with a `-maxdepth 1`

Answer (score 12):

You can do this in  terminal:

```
cd dirA 
export GLOBIGNORE=a.txt
rm *
export GLOBIGNORE=
```

Comment: Does not work if you set full path

Answer (score 5):

You can use the command :

```
find ! -name 'a.txt' -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

This will look for files (`-type f`) in the current directory except for file `a.txt` (`! -name 'a.txt`) and then will remove them (`-exec rm -f {} +`)

Comment: But  this would not remove the directories if exist?!

Comment: @Maythux Yes, the author asks how to remove files, not folders.

Comment: `-exec rm -f {} +` doesn't really have any advantages over `-delete`.

Answer (score 5):

Use `find` and `xargs`

```
find folder -type f -not -name 'a.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

To exclude multiple things:

```
find folder -type f -not -name 'a.txt' -not -name 'b.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

This also works with wildcards:

```
find folder -type f -not -name '*.png' -not -name 'b.txt' -print0  | xargs -0 rm
```

To search in the current folder, use `.` in place of 'folder'.

[Base source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325216/rm-all-files-except-some)

Comment: Probably will be good for portability =) +1

Comment: Note that this will fail if your file names contain whitespace or newlines or glob characters etc. Use `find . -type f -not -name 'a.txt' -delete` instead.