# move all files except with extension

Tags: command-line, wildcards

I have moved a tar.bz2 from my Downloads to /usr/src, which is where I like to put all things that I install on my system. Now I extracted the file and I want to move its contents to /usr/share/icons. But I do not want to move the tar.bz2 itself:

```
# ls -l | grep Comix
-rw-rw-r--  1 guarddog guarddog   2190951 May 26 11:03 ComixCursors-0.8.2.tar.bz2
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root          4096 Oct 23  2013 ComixCursors-Black
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root          4096 Oct 23  2013 ComixCursors-Blue
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root          4096 Oct 23  2013 ComixCursors-Green
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root          4096 Oct 23  2013 ComixCursors-Orange
```

In the output command I want to move everything besides the tar.bz2, within the terminal.

I tried the following but unfortunately it moves the tar.bz2 as well:

```
 mv Comix*[!tar.bz] /usr/local/share
```

I expected the negation operator to exclude the file ending wit tar.bz. The solution below is what I was looking for, didn't want to use find with complicated flags.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164025/exclude-one-pattern-from-glob-match

Comment: This is better:- http://askubuntu.com/a/624449/408593

Comment: @SharadGautam I would like to down vote your answer..why have you used `export` ?

Comment: It was for that question's OP @heemayl

Comment: @SharadGautam That question can be solved without using `export`..although you have unset it later on, `export` is totally needless there

Comment: Sorry though and thanks for pointing out  to this OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GLOBIGNORE` variable of `bash`:

```
GLOBIGNORE=ComixCursors-0.8.2.tar.bz2
```

Now run:

```
mv ComixCursors* /usr/share/icons/
```

Also note that when you are done with the operation it is good to `unset` the variable to avoid unwanted scenarios:

```
unset GLOBIGNORE
```

Or

```
GLOBIGNORE=
```

Comment: @Arronical yes..it would be sensible if you are done with it..No, it does not automatically `unset` itself..

Answer (score 1):

Use the good old `find`:

```
find /usr/src -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "Comix*[^\.tar\.bz2]" -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 mv {} /usr/share/icons/
```

Comment: @Arronical Then write your answer :)

Comment: @Arronical `ComixCursors-Blue2` doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a simple command to use, for example in your Home Dir. we have a folder "Xtest" which contains `test.tar.gz` and `test.txt`, `test2.txt` etc. and an empty folder "Xtest2" where we want to move all files except `.tar.gz` then:

```
cd ~/Xtest
mv !(test.tar.gz) ~/Xtest2
```

All the content except `test.tar.gz` will be moved to `Xtest2` folder.