# how would i use rm to delete all files without certain wildcard?

Tags: rm

using `rm *text*` you can delete all files which have a certain string in them. How would I make it so that it removes every file *except* for the ones with the specific wildcard?

I have attempted to use other things I've found, such as:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs --null grep -Z -L 'text' | xargs --null rm
```

or

```
grep -r -L -Z 'text' . | xargs --null rm
```

but these do not work. Instead, they are deleting all files in a given directory.

How could I do this?

Comment: Bash extended globbing (`extglob`) provides a negation operator - see for example [How to delete all files except one named file from a specific folder](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624441/how-to-delete-all-files-except-one-named-file-from-a-specific-folder)

Comment: FWIW the issue with your `find` attempts is that they grep for the names of files whose *contents* do not match `text`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this by enabling extended globs:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Now you can do for instance

```
ls !(*.pdf)
```

Or in your example

```
rm !(*text*)
```

Answer (score 3):

With `find`:

```
find . -type f -not -name "*text*" -exec rm {} \;
```

Note that this will remove all files not matching the specified pattern (`*text*`) in the current folder and its subfolders.

If you need to remove only files found in the current folder you can use the `-maxdepth 1` flag:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -not -name "*text*" -exec rm {} \;
```