# Delete all files having extension '.sh' but keep one file matching the extension by terminal

Tags: command-line, find

Actually this kind of too much to ask I think.

But I want to remove all files matching the extension ".sh"(current folder only) which I can do with below command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' -exec rm {} +
```

But still I want to keep file "cron.sh" in the current folder unaffected.

How can I achieve this in single command line ?

Comment: With extended globbing: `rm -- !(cron).sh`

Comment: @steeldriver damn! I was trying to figure that one out using `rm !(cron.sh)` and couldn't find a way for it to not delete non-sh files. Nice one! Please post it as  an answer.

Comment: @terdon it *is* given in [one of the answers in the dupe](http://askubuntu.com/a/256650/178692) - I was in the process of writing it as an answer here when it got locked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `-not`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.sh' -not -name cron.sh -delete
```

Also, GNU `find` has the `-delete` option which is simpler to use and than `rm -rf`.

**Important**: Always put `-delete` at the end. As explained in `man find`:

> Warnings:  Don't  forget that the find command line is evaluated
>                 as an expression, so putting -delete first will make find try to
>                 delete everything below the starting points you specified.

---

Alternatively, you could use a shell loop (but don't, the `find` command above is far more efficient):

```
for f in *.sh; do [ "$f" = "cron.sh" ] || rm "$f"; done
```

Comment: Thank you, please keep both the answers. So I can use `-name` and `-not -name` in same line, any disadvantages with them ?

Comment: @VickyDev um, no. What kind of disadvantages? You can do very complicated things with `find`. You can string multiple conditions together (`-not`, `-or`, `-and`) and use `\(` and `\)` for more complex grouping. This is very simple and one line should be fine.

Comment: Maybe you could point out that `find`'s command execution is "left to right" so when using `-delete` to make sure to put it at the end. People have suffered from this often enough. Oh, the terrible nightmares are haunting me to this day....

Comment: I rarely the gnu one, but if you are going the gnu find way, can you add  " +" after "-delete" to have it work on multiple files at once (with less forking)?  or is it not possible with -delete?

Comment: @OlivierDulac no, at least on GNU `find`, the `+` only makes sense with `-exec` and `-execdir`. The `-delete` command doesn't take any arguments.  As for being GNU `find`, yes, that's the only implementation that's on topic here. This is [ubuntu.se], after all.

Comment: With `*.sh` and bash, `GLOBIGNORE` is far more convenient, IMO.

Comment: @OlivierDulac I just tested this by comparing the times of `-delete`, `-exec rm {} \;` and `-exec rm {} +` and the `-delete` was the fastest. I am assuming it calls `unlink()` directly and doesn't fork at all since it isn't calling any external commands.

Comment: @muru well,  `GLOBIGNORE="cron.sh" rm *.sh` doesn't work (on my system, anyway). It deletes `cron.sh` as well. So you'd need to first run `GLOBIGNORE="cron.sh"` and then `rm *.sh`. And that does work, but leaves `GLOBIGNORE` set for the session. I prefer `find`.

Comment: Well, yes: `GLOBIGNORE="cron.sh"; rm *.sh`, and as for the variable being kept alive: `(GLOBIGNORE="cron.sh"; rm *.sh)`.

Comment: @muru ah, yes, using a subshell is a good idea. Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: @terdon I closed it as a dupe sometime ago. :D

Comment: @terdon: it makes sense (that it unlinks directly), and indeed that makes it faster (no forking, and find already has the info "at hand" for the unlink). Thanks for looking it up

Comment: @muru so I see. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative, but slower way then the great `find` example by [terdon](https://askubuntu.com/users/85695/terdon) is to use `mv` and `rm` commands chained with and operators.

```
mv cron.sh cron.sh.safe && rm *.sh && mv cron.sh.safe cron.sh
```

This will complain if you have any directories named something.sh, but will not delete them.